# Carto Help in minimizing geographic dataset

Tags: data-request, geospatial, tool-request, geocoding

I have a file that contains location points all over the world, using lat long coordinates. I am trying to trim it down to only new York and Newark new jersey. I have a shape file that is the boundaries of new York and includes new jersey but is in shape area and shape length. I am trying to extract the data points that fall in those boundaries but I am stuck. Does anyone know how to do this in carto or any other program?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with SQL and PostGIS in Carto's SQL tray. If your table of NY boundaries is `ny_boundaries` and your point dataset is `points_data`, then the following query will do the filtering for you:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM points_data As p
JOIN ny_boundaries As n
ON ST_Intersects(p.the_geom, n.the_geom)
```

You can leave the query applied to keep that view of the data, or create a new dataset from the query.

Docs on Carto's SQL tray: https://carto.com/docs/carto-editor/managing-your-data/#running-sql-queries
Lessons on SQL: https://carto.com/academy/courses/sql-postgis/